# define a function use callable object as argument

Tags: c++, stl

thank you checking my question. I need a template function to use a callable object(like lambda, function object, bind, function pointer, and function) as arguments just like what STL does, but I really have no idea how to do it, and there is no resource online.

To be specific, I want design a function to traverse my container, and for each element, it will call the callable function to manipulate the element just like STL::for_each(). Could you please give a example like this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: To increase your chances of getting help. you should try and code a small example of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The STL uses templates to do this. Something like this:

```
template<class CallableObjectType>
void do_stuff(/* other arguments */, CallableObjectType object)
{
    // ...
    object(arg1, arg2, arg3);
    // ...
}
```

Which is to say, *it doesn't* try to force your object to be callable, except by calling it. If the object is not callable then the template cannot be instantiated, because `object(arg1, arg2, arg3)` is invalid, so you get an error. If the object is callable then it works how you'd expect.